# Custom liquid functions in jekyll projects

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I was wonder how could I include my own [Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) filters and functions to a [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) project

Jekyll provide its set of liquid filters and functions, but I would like to increase this set with my own. How could I do this?

And, also, would it work in [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/)?

Comment: have a look at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/ . This will not work on Github Pages but can work at other places like https://netlify.com.

Comment: If you want to stick with GitHub Pages and thus stay plugin-free, check this out: https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugins/